# Double free or memory allocation error

Tags: c++, opencv, out-of-memory

I am new to C++ programming and I meet this problem in one part of my code, where the error is sometimes memory allocation type error and sometimes it is double free error.

Erroneous code is as below.

```
cv::Mat obstacles = cv::Mat::ones(output.size(), CV_8UC1);

for (int r=0; r<obstacles.rows; ++r) {
    int x_cord = cvRound((r - intercet)/slope);
    if (x_cord  >= 0 && x_cord <= disp_size){
        for (int c=0; c<obstacles.cols; ++c) {
                int d = output.at<int>(r,c);
                if ((d/(256/disp_size)) <= x_cord+5){//<= x_cord+5 && d>= x_cord-5){
                obstacles.at<int>(r,c) = 0;  //error is in this line
            }
        }
   }
}
```

If I remove `obstacles.at<int>(r,c) = 0;` line, there will not be any errors.

I do not understand this, because `r` and `c` are just the `obstacles` matrix row and column numbers respectively.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mat has type `CV_8UC1` which is a 8 Bit = 1 Byte data type.

You try to access as `.at<int>` but int is a 32 Bit data type.

Please try to use unsigned char or other 8 bit type as shown below:

```
cv::Mat obstacles = cv::Mat::ones(output.size(), CV_8UC1);

for (int r=0; r<obstacles.rows; ++r) {
int x_cord = cvRound((r - intercet)/slope);
if (x_cord  >= 0 && x_cord <= disp_size){
    for (int c=0; c<obstacles.cols; ++c) {
            int d = output.at<uchar>(r,c);
            if ((d/(256/disp_size)) <= x_cord+5){//<= x_cord+5 && d>= x_cord-5){
            obstacles.at<uchar>(r,c) = 0;  //error is in this line
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I had trouble in understanding how it is working. Thanks